# Is there a quick way to add all undefined methods?

Tags: eclipse

Lately I've been using a lot of JUnit tests which have the predefined names for methods I will need to implement in my code. I find the "Create method 'x'" tool very useful but I was wondering if there was a tool that creates all the undefined methods, would anyone happen to know? This really isn't a huge problem but it would be very convenient for me to just add all of the missing methods at once as opposed to one by one.

Comment: I presume it would be difficult because the calling conventions are loose enough that there are potentially many functions that could be called with the specific arguments given in any testing call. Should parameters be typed `Object` or with a specific interface or with a generic type, etc.

Comment: @Mitch Salopek: I find your question is a bit unclear... You have a junit test of some class, and you would like to create "undefined methods". In what sense are the methods undefined?

Comment: @mtsz When I say undefined methods, I mean that the JUnit test is intended to test certain methods within my code but I have not written those methods yet. This is very useful for students as our professors sometimes give us JUnit tests. I like to use the JUnit tests to generate my methods but I typically have to do it one by one. Doing this is a good way to get started on my projects because then I'm sure I have all of the required methods and I have named everything correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that is not possible. Eclipse is able to generate all methods which you need to implement an interface, but you do not seem to have an interface here. If I understand your scenario right, you get Unit-Tests which do not compile because your class does not provide the tested methods yet.

When the class exists already, then Eclipse should suggest you to create a method with the needed signature. That is what you probably mean with "one by one".
In your case the fastest way is:

- create the class
- go into your unit test
- jump through all non-compiling methods using `command` + `.` and create the methods using auto-suggest